# (ApiException.class) -> from java to C#?

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

How to convert this code from java to c#?

```
LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
```

getResult gets a Class object as a parameter. So my questions is how to translate ApiException.class to C#? How to get the Class object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Henrique Forlani answer gave me a clue how to do it. The correct conversion is

```
task.GetResult(Class.FromType(typeof(ApiException)))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's typeof(ApiException) in C#